# Converting and storing integers to ASCII Characters

Tags: java, integer, character, ascii

I recently started learning Java in college and I have been working for hours on a solution to a problem. I ran into a problem while trying to convert integers that are randomly generated using java.util.Random and convert them into characters using an ASCII table.

These two things are required for the assignment as well. The end goal is salting a password so I've been trying to get these integers to stay as characters so that I can add them together so that I can then add that onto a provided password.

The issue is I've tried multiple things such as casting in every instance such as when I'm printing, casting before the number generator, and casting the variables set with the number generator.

Some examples of what I've tried are:

```
// The seed is gotten through user input earlier.
Random rand = new Random(seed);

// This is how we were taught to do ranges when generating numbers
// 122 is the max in the range and 65 is the lowest
// Basically it is narrowing it down to capital A and lower case z for the ASCII range
char saltExample = (char)(rand.nextInt(122 - 65 + 1) + 65); 
char saltExample2 = (char)(rand.nextInt(122 - 65 + 1) + 65);

System.out.println(saltExample);
System.out.println(saltExample + saltExample2);
```

The first print actually outputs a character. When given the seed 5 it outputs L, but the second print outputs a number which I assume is the two integers generated together. It outputs 181, in case you were wondering.

For the assignment I'm supposed to generate 5 characters for the salt, yet I cannot even get two together. My main question is how can I convert integers to characters that I can actually add together into a string using an ASCII table? Also any other feedback is much appreciated.

If anyone is curious as to what I am looking at for the ASCII table this is what my professor provided: https://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

I am planning on going to bed soon as it is late while I am writing this and I have class in the morning, so if I get any responses that is most likely why I haven't replied. Thanks in advance for any help received!

Comment: Use a char array which can easily be converted to a String.

Comment: Yes thank you very much! For some reason I had never thought of a solution like one of the ones presented in that thread.